# Allow access to website only at specific times?

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to restrict the access to a html/php website only at specific times? I have a php file on my Raspberry Pi and I already set up a .htaccess file so that users have to log in, but I also want to restrict the times of access. Users should only be able to access (or log in) the page between 7am and 1pm.
Since I have root access to my Raspberry Pi, I kind of have infinite possibilities to do so (apache2, html, css, javascript, php, ...)

Comment: cron task to shutdown apache at a set time, and start it up again at a set time

Comment: You will have to be more specific - what method are you intending to use? Do you want to block the entire server or only one specific site?

Comment: javascript isn't really a valid method though, as it can easily be disabled/modified

Comment: @Lix: only one file, but it's solved anyway now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redirect users to a different page if the time criteria isn't met with the Apache Rewrite mod. The below will issue a 403 if the time is later than 1300 and before 0700.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >= 13 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} < 07
RewriteRule ^/site.html - [F]
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks, is it also possible to make a RewriteCond which allows access only during the week and not on the weekend?

Comment: That's going to be tricky using this method - Take a look at TIME_DAY but I'm fairly sure that returns the day of the month, i.e. 0 - 31.

Answer (score -1):

if you have(most probably you do) a file that gets included every refresh, you could just check the time and display a "no access" page incase it falls in the time, where the site should be not accessed

Tell me if you need more help